# Read bytes in NanoHttpd post with octet-stream

Tags: java, android, inputstream, datainputstream, nanohttpd

I am using **Nanohttpd** in **Android** to create an app that receives bytes from other instance of the same app. In my case, my application works and send data normally to a web service, but when I tried to send data between two instance of this application, when I debugged I saw strange bytes like trash or for example different encoding. I tried to use InputStream from NanoHttpd.

My code send data with a java code:

```
public class MainTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.215:8080");
            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpConnection.setUseCaches(false);
            httpConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(4096);
            httpConnection.setConnectTimeout(1000 * 5);
            httpConnection.setReadTimeout(1000 * 5);
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpConnection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
            httpConnection.addRequestProperty("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");
            httpConnection.addRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            OutputStream out = httpConnection.getOutputStream();

            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(out);
            dataOutputStream.writeInt(37);
            dataOutputStream.close();
            httpConnection.getResponseMessage();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In Android, I want to read bytes from the last code, my code is:

```
@Override
        public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {
            Method method = session.getMethod();
            try {
                if (Method.POST.equals(method)) {
                    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(session.getInputStream());
                    int value = in.readInt();
                    Log.d("nextValue: ", value); // expected 37
                } else {
                    return executeGet(session);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                return newFixedLengthResponse(Response.Status.INTERNAL_ERROR, NanoHTTPD.MIME_PLAINTEXT,
                        "SERVER MOBILE INTERNAL ERROR: : " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

I need to use main java sample to send bytes, sometimes I need to writeUtf etc., because I've an app that works the same.